# Internal Server Error. Did you create and train the service?

Tags: java, solr, watson

Hi I am experimenting with cranfield collection set by running liberty server locally. I have uploaded the collection, along with sample documents and training questions in csv format. I also ran train.py script and when I checked the ranker status it showed "The ranker instance is now available and is ready to take ranker requests.". Now when I run my application http://localhost:9080/webApp and select a random question, I am getting Internal Server Error. Did you create and train the service?

When I debugged to see what is happening, processSolrRequest in SolrUtils.java is throwing an exception. Can anybody help?

Comment: What exception are you getting? Are your Solr server working if you access it directly?

Comment: I dont know how to print java exception. Yes if I use directly and solr server is working. Please let me know how to print the Java exception

Comment: You said that when you're debugging, you're getting an exception in SolrUtils.java?